# Perl: Fastest way to find files older than X number of minutes, sorted oldest to newest

Tags: perl, file, sorting, find

im trying to check if there is a file (i dont care about folders) that older than X minuts. unfortunatly i can;t tell where is my bug on this code.
i will appriciate any help :)

**1. Find the files older than X number of minute**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my $maindir = "C:\\Users\\Dor\\Desktop\\aba";
my $minutesold = 60;
my $now = time;
my $filedisc;

# Declare arrays
my @xmlfiles;
my @qulfiedfiles; 

# Declare a Dictionary
my %filedisc;

opendir(my $dh, $maindir) or die "opendir($maindir): $!";

 # Read all the files
 while (my $de = readdir($dh)) 
 {
    # get the Full path of the file
    my $f = $maindir . $de;

    if ( -f $f )
    {

        push (@xmlfiles, $f); 

    }
}
    closedir($dh);


 # For every file in directory
 for my $file (@xmlfiles) {

    # Get stats about a file
    my @stats = stat($file);

    # If time stamp is older than minutes provided
    if ($stats[9] >= ($now - (( $minutesold * 60) ))){

       # Put the File and Time stamp in the dictionary
       print($stats[9] ."          .|           "  .$file ."\n\n");

    }

    #print($now ."\n")
    #print($now - ( $minutesold * 60) ."\n"); 
 }
```

Comment: what goes wrong when you run it?  have you looked at @xmlfiles and verified the right filenames are getting added to it?

Comment: Stuff like `# Declare arrays` is ridiculous. If you can't see what the ensuing lines are doing then you don't have a hope of understanding the code, comments or not. It is twenty or more years out of date to pepper your code with comments just for the sake of it, and it is best to use sensible identifiers to express your ideas. You need comments only when the code is obscure or unidiomatic (perhaps due to an optimisation) or when it is unclear *why* the code is there. Neither apply to any of the comments in this code, so they serve only to obscure it. `# Read all the files` is outright wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this in kind of a functional programming style is the way to go here I think:

```
my $dir = shift() || $ENV{HOME}; #command line arg or else home dir
my $minutesold = 60; #1h                                                                                                                                                                                            
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "ERR: opendir($dir) $!\n";

print
map     "$$_{timestamp}          .|            $$_{file}\n",
#sort   { $$a{timestamp} <=> $$b{timestamp} }  # sort by age
#sort   { $$a{file}      cmp $$b{file}      }  # sort by name
grep    $^T-$$_{timestamp} >= 60*$minutesold,  # $^T is program startup time()
map     {{timestamp=>(stat($_))[9], file=>$_}}
grep    -f $_,
map     "$dir/$_",
readdir $dh;

closedir $dh;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's usually best to use `glob` rather than `opendir`/`readdir`, so as to avoid having to “rebuild” the full path to the file for every result

You will probably want to enable the `:bsd_glob` option on Windows so that paths with spaces, such as `C:\Program Files`, are handled correctly

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'; # Provide for spaces in path

my $root       = 'C:\Users\Dor\Desktop\aba';
my $minutesold = 60;

my @old_files = grep { -f and -M * 24 * 60 > $minutes_old } glob "$root\\*.*";
```

Comment: This is the output im getting: Argument "*main::24" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at C:\Users\Dor\Desktop
\folderTest.pl line 27.

Comment: FYI for those who might wonder: `perldoc -f -M` for the `-M` option.

Answer (score 1):

The path and file isn't correct.

```
my $f = $maindir . $de;
```

Should be (add slash between path and file)

```
my $f = "$maindir/$de";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one simple way to get the modification time of file in perl: the -M switch.

```
    my $modifiedTimeinDays = -M "$file";

    my $modifiedTimeinSec = $modifiedTimeinDays*60*60*24;

    if($modifiedTimeinSec > 60)
    {
       # file older than 60 sec
    }
```

As simple as that.

See [perldoc -f -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to learn about all of the file tests.

Comment: im getting a blank output. i tried it for one file in a folder:

`#!/usr/bin/perl 

my $maindir = "C:\\Users\\Dor\\Desktop\\aba\\a.txt";
my $filename = "a.txt";

my $age = -M $maindir;
print $age; `

Comment: @lol Add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` to the top of your script. It'll tell you whether `$age` is undefined, which likely in this case will mean the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Re "*which likely in this case will mean the file doesn't exist*", The exact error will be found in `$!`

Comment: You need to *“See perldoc -f -X to learn about all of the file tests”* **yourself**. `-M` returns the age of a file (at the point when the Perl program was started) in ***days***. Please be more careful to post accurate information. Imagining that you were editing a Wikipedia page often helps.

Comment: @lol, can you try giving the file name string in double quotes? `if( -e "$maindir") { my $age = -M "$maindir"; } else { print "File doesnt exist\n"; }` and see what you get? If still the same error then maybe in windows it doesnt work.

Comment: @SrihariKaranth: Programming by wild guesswork is very rarely fruitful, and is likely to create buggy code. Enclosing a string variable in double quotes is *wrong* in general, and your program would work fine on Windows except that `-M` returns a file's age in ***days*** as I've already written.